# How to temporarily disable Xfce monitor power off via bash

Tags: power-management, screensaver, gsettings

I have set up my monitor to go off after some minutes of inactivity, but when watching an internet stream in a browser this is unwanted, thus I'd like to have bash command that to disable (and later re-enable) the setting of "Power Manager: Settings for Xfce Power Manager": Entry `On AC`, Tab `Monitor`